# Unable to access a custom header in HTTP response

Tags: javascript, http, xmlhttprequest, phantomjs, cors

I have a node js server in which i am setting a custom header. To allow it to be accessed by browser i have set Access-control-expose-header. Using this i am able to get the header in Chrome Firefox but it is giving a error in Phantomjs "Refused to get unsafe header". How can i get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get around this you need to set 'webSecurityEnabled' header  as 'false' in options while opening a page using PhantomJs.

Checkout the options listed here 
https://github.com/nathanboktae/mocha-phantomjs#usage